# query set in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

i really need help with this:
I have 3 models say User,Item and Comment where User is a foreign key in Item and Item is a foreign key in Comment.
i want to get all comment belonging to a particular user in my view, how do i achieve it. bellow is are my model

```
 class User(models.Model):
        name= models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

 class Item(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
        name= models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

 class Comment(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE)
        name= models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Comment: thank you all, the user field in the comment model is actually item, i made a typo error.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED 2**

You should consider changing model, like [amadou-sow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15042684/amadou-sow) said, that is right way to do such things

**UPDATED**

```
def get_user_comments(request):
    qs = Comment.objects.filter(user__user=request.user)
```

You could access yours related objects with "__" (double _) read more in [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/lookups/)

And you really should rename "user" field to "item" in Comment model   if it is foreign key to Item model, like this:

```
 class User(models.Model):
        name= models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

 class Item(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
        name= models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

 class Comment(models.Model):
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

#view.py
def get_user_comments(request):
    return Comment.objects.filter(item__user=request.user)
```

Comment: this is not correct because user is a foreignerkey of Item not User.edit your answer

Comment: yep, my mistake, was confused by "user = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE)", updated the answer

Comment: now it is better.i upvoted your answer

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem of design model in your code.
here is how you can do it.

```
 class Comment(models.Model):
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE)  # the related item
        author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE) #new ( the author of the comment)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

now in your views.py you can do something like this.

```
Comment.objects.filter(author=request.user)
```